# Database design for MLM/Pyramiding

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm developing an MLM/Pyramid relation database design. I'm struggling on how to connect them and get the correct design.

So basically for example If Customer 1 recruits Customer 2 and Customer 3  he will get 50$ each
then if Customer 2 or 3 recruits Customer 4 and Customer 5 then Customer 1 will get 25$ each
then if Customer 4 or 5 recruits Customer 6 and Customer 7 then Customer 1 will get 15$ each
then if Customer 6 or 7 recruits Customer 8 and Customer 9 then Customer 1 will get 10$ each
then if Customer 8 or 9 recruits Customer 10 and Customer 11 then Customer 1 will get 5$ each
then if Customer 10 or 11 recruits another one customer 1 won't get any referral fee

There is no limit on how many they can recruit.
Also, this referral system applied to all customers.
So Since Customer 2 or 3 recruits Customer 4 and 5 then Customer 2 or 3 will get the first level 50$ and so on and so forth.

Now I'm trying to create a relation table for this and I'm using the child and parent pattern but I think it's not applicable since I would lose connection on lower levels.

| id | user_parent | user_child | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | customer1 | customer2 | 50 |
| 2 | customer1 | customer3 | 50 |
| 3 | customer2 | customer4 | 50 |
| 4 | customer2 | customer5 | 50 |

This is where I'm lost how can I tell that customer1 will get 25$ since customer 2 recruits customer 4 and 5?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: And you will use MLM to do what?

Comment: Thanks for the link this helps a lot I'll check on it. The MLM is a project that I've been working on for a small business here locally

Comment: With this approach how can I get the amount difference for each level? the 50,25,15,10,5?